# PERMISSION_DENIED: User does not have USE CATALOG on Catalog '__databricks_internal'

Tags: pyspark, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

Developing delta live pipelines in DataBricks, I get this error: `PERMISSION_DENIED: User does not have USE CATALOG on Catalog '__databricks_internal'`.  How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to DataBricks->Catalogs and add appropriate permissions (DataBricks does not inherit at this level of its Catalog system).